# Set equal height of images in carousel

Tags: css, reactjs, react-elastic-carousel

I'm using `react-elastic-carousel`, and trying to enforce all images to be the same height. However, if I set the width `100%`, the heights are all different. How can I make sure all images are the same height, without squishing or stretching the images?

Current state of carousel: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-elastic-carousel-forked-q5hc9?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: You can't make an image same height and width without affecting the aspect ratio unless you crop it AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a fixed height to the `.slideImage` (ex: `height: 200px;`) and add  `object-fit: cover` so the image doesn't stretch and fills the entire space.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-elastic-carousel-forked-sq53v?file=/src/styles.css:404-441)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
.rec-item-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto !important;
}

.slideImage {
  max-height: 310px; //This was the max-height already set
  width: auto;
}
```

I'm still learning CSS but I hope it helps.